# Jq to string filter

Tags: json, jq

Trying to filter the output from Json, so far the filter used works as expected when , the software version is found .However when the software version is not present , jq will result in a error. Basically how do I escape the () and return empty in the csv file.

```
.result [] | [ "https://vuldb.com/?id." + .entry.id ,.software.vendor // "empty"
,.software.name // "empty", (.software.version []| tostring // "empty")
,.software.type // "empty"
,.software.platform //"empty" ]
```

```
    "result": [
        {
            "entry": {
                "id": "206880",
                "title": "CrowdStrike Falcon 6.31.14505.0\/6.42.15610 Uninstallation authorization",
                "summary": "A vulnerability was found in CrowdStrike Falcon 6.31.14505.0\/6.42.15610. It has been classified as problematic. Affected is some unknown functionality of the component Uninstallation Handler. There is no information about possible countermeasures known. It may be suggested to replace the affected object with an alternative product.",
                "details": {
                    "affected": "A vulnerability was found in CrowdStrike Falcon 6.31.14505.0\/6.42.15610. It has been classified as problematic.",
                    "vulnerability": "CWE is classifying the issue as CWE-862. The software does not perform an authorization check when an actor attempts to access a resource or perform an action.",
                    "impact": "This is going to have an impact on availability.",
                    "exploit": "It is declared as functional. The vulnerability was handled as a non-public zero-day exploit for at least 54 days. During that time the estimated underground price was around $0-$5k.",
                    "countermeasure": "There is no information about possible countermeasures known. It may be suggested to replace the affected object with an alternative product.",
                    "sources": "Further details are available at modzero.com."
                },
                "timestamp": {
                    "create": "1661155277",
                    "change": "1661155462"
                },
                "changelog": [
                    "vulnerability_cvss3_meta_basescore",
                    "vulnerability_cvss3_meta_tempscore",
                    "vulnerability_cvss3_researcher_basescore"
                ]
            },
            "software": {
                "vendor": "CrowdStrike",
                "name": "Falcon",
                "version": [
                    "6.31.14505.0",
                    "6.42.15610"
                ],
```

Comment: With the [Error Suppression Operator](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#ErrorSuppression%2FOptionalOperator%3A%3F) `?` you can suppress the error. And in combination with the [Alternative Operator](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Alternativeoperator%3A%2F%2F) `//` you can emit a fall-back value, if needed (as you already do with other columns): `(.software.version[] | tostring // "empty")? // "no version"` [Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/4S3_lrwPL_m)

Comment: Thank you , that gave me the result I expected, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Suppress the error and provide an alternative for empty values:

```
.result | map(
    "https://vuldb.com/?id.\(.entry.id)",
    (
        .software |
        .vendor // "empty",
        .name // "empty",
        (.version[] | tostring // "empty")? // "no version",
        .type // "empty",
        .platform // "empty"
    )
)
```