# JQ if else then NULL Return

Tags: arrays, json, bash, jq

I'm trying to filter and output from JSON with `jq`.

The API will sometime return an object and sometime an array, I want to catch the result using an `if` statement and return empty string when the object/array is not available.

```
{
    "result": 
        {
            "entry": {
                "id": "207579",
                "title": "Realtek Bluetooth Mesh SDK on Linux\/Android Segmented Packet reference buffer overflow",
                "summary": "A vulnerability, which was classified as critical, was found in Realtek Bluetooth Mesh SDK on Linux\/Android (the affected version unknown). This affects an unknown functionality of the component Segmented Packet Handler. There is no information about possible countermeasures known. It may be suggested to replace the affected object with an alternative product.",
                "details": {
                    "affected": "A vulnerability, which was classified as critical, was found in Realtek Bluetooth Mesh SDK on Linux\/Android (the affected version unknown).",
                    "vulnerability": "The manipulation of the argument reference with an unknown input leads to a unknown weakness. CWE is classifying the issue as CWE-120. The program copies an input buffer to an output buffer without verifying that the size of the input buffer is less than the size of the output buffer, leading to a buffer overflow.",
                    "impact": "This is going to have an impact on confidentiality, integrity, and availability.",
                    "countermeasure": "There is no information about possible countermeasures known. It may be suggested to replace the affected object with an alternative product."
                },
                "timestamp": {
                    "create": "1661860801",
                    "change": "1661861110"
                },
                "changelog": [
                    "software_argument"
                ]
            },
            "software": {
                "vendor": "Realtek",
                "name": "Bluetooth Mesh SDK",
                "platform": [
                    "Linux",
                    "Android"
                ],
                "component": "Segmented Packet Handler",
                "argument": "reference",
                "cpe": [
                    "cpe:\/a:realtek:bluetooth_mesh_sdk"
                ],
                "cpe23": [
                    "cpe:2.3:a:realtek:bluetooth_mesh_sdk:*:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
                ]
            }
        }
    
}
```

Would also like to  to use the statement globally for the whole array output so I can parse it to .csv and escape the null, since sofware name , can also contain an array or an object. Having a global `if` statement with simplify the syntax  result and suppress the error with `?`

The error i received from `bash`

```
jq  -r '.result []   |  [ "https://vuldb.com/?id." + .entry.id ,.software.vendor // "empty",(.software.name | if type!="array" then [.] | join (",")  else . //"empty" end  )?,.software.type //  "empty",(.software.platform | if type!="array" then []  else . | join (",") //"empty" end )?] | @csv' > tst.csv
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  7452    0  7393  100    59   4892     39  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--  4935
jq: error (at <stdin>:182): Cannot iterate over null (null)
```

What I have tried is the following code which i tried to demo https://jqplay.org/ which is incorrect syntax

```
.result [] |( if .[] == null  then // "empty" else . end 
| ,software.name // "empty" ,.software.platform |if type!="array" then [.]  // "empty" else . | join (",")  end)
```

Current output

```
[
  [
    "Bluetooth Mesh SDK"
  ],
  "Linux,Android"
]
```

Desired outcome

```
[
  
  "Bluetooth Mesh SDK",
  "empty"
]
```

Comment: So what doesn't work? Please fix your input JSON and explain what doesn't work!

Comment: There also seem to be obvious typos in your `jq` script.

Comment: This is a sample from the JSON return, the issues is that if use 

```.result [] | [.software.name // "empty",.software.platform |if type!="array" then [.]  // "empty" else . | join (",")  end]'```

the output is correct , however if the array does not exist or the object for that matter the with the current syntax ```jq``` does not check for null and outputs the empty string as ```//empty``` , therefore cannot parse it to .csv because is not a valid .

Comment: Again: both your JSON and your `jq` script contain multiple errors. Please try to focus our efforts on the actual problem you are seeking help with by fixing these accidental and tangential errors.

Comment: I have fixed the input as suggested and tried the solution below my comment .

Comment: Please condense your sample input to the smallest input required to show your problem (the M...inimal from MWE). Show both inputs (array AND object). Fix the syntax errors in your jq program. Then and only then can the Stackoverflow community help.

Comment: @def0to And I knew that this JSON looked very similar. How is this question different from your question a week before? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73458432/jq-to-string-filter

Comment: Can you show the different versions of "can contain an array or object" too?

Answer (score 0):

After fixing your input JSON, I think you can get the desired output by using the following JQ filter:

```
if (.result | type) == "array" then . else (.result |= [.]) end \
    | .result[].software | [ .name, (.platform // [ "Empty" ] | join(",")) ]
```

Where

- `if (.result | type) == "array" then . else (.result |= [.]) end`
  Wraps `.result` in an array if `type` isn't array
- `.result[].software`
  Loops though the `software` in each `.result` obj
- `[ .name, (.platform // [ "Empty" ] | join(",")) ]`
  Create an array with `.name` and `.platform` (which is replaced by `[ "Empty" ]` when it doesn't exist. Then it's `join()`'d to a string

---

Outcome:

```json
[
  "Bluetooth Mesh SDK",
  "Linux,Android"
]
```

[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/pYhInDK_Vez)

Or

```json
[
  "Bluetooth Mesh SDK",
  "Empty
]
```

[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/2VX_gABa-vv)

Comment: Thank you for the proposed solution , this works only if the input is type ```array``` , however if it ```object``` it will not work .
 https://jqplay.org/s/w8cy6iIz4m3